# Is this the proper way to count the number of 0s in a binary number?

Tags: c, binary, bit

```
#include <stdio.h>

int NumberOfSetBits(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size_of_int = sizeof(int);
    int total_bit_size = size_of_int * 8;

    // binary representation of 3 is 0000011 
    // C standard doesn't support binary representation directly
    int n = 3; 
    int count = NumberOfSetBits(n);
    printf("Number of set bits is: %d\n", count);
    printf("Number of unset bits is: %d", total_bit_size - count);
}

int NumberOfSetBits(int x)
{
    int count = 0;
    //printf("x is: %d\n", x);
    while (x != 0) {
        //printf("%d\n", x);
        count += (x & 1);
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

> Number of set bits is: 2
>
> Number of unset bits is: 30

```
int size_of_int = sizeof(int);
int total_bit_size = size_of_int * 8;
```

^ that will get the size of the int on the system and times it by 8 which is the number of bits in each byte

EDITED: Without the use of the ~

```
/*
    Calculate how many set bits and unset bits are in a binary number aka how many 1s and 0s in a binary number
*/
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int NumberOfSetBits(unsigned int);
unsigned int NumberOfUnSetBits(unsigned int x);


int main() {

    // binary representation of 3 is 0000011 
    // C standard doesn't support binary representation directly    
    unsigned int n = 3; 
    printf("Number of set bits is: %u\n", NumberOfSetBits(n));
    printf("Number of unset bits is: %u", NumberOfUnSetBits(n));

    return 0;
}

unsigned int NumberOfSetBits(unsigned int x) {
    // counts the number of 1s
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        count += (x & 1);
        // moves to the next bit
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return count;
}

unsigned int NumberOfUnSetBits(unsigned int x) {

    // counts the number of 0s
    unsigned int count = 0; 
    while(x != 0) {
        if ((x & 1) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        // moves to the next bit
        x = x >> 1; 
    }
    return count;
}
```

returns for input 3

```
Number of set bits is: 2
Number of unset bits is: 0
```

unset bits is 0? Doesn't seem right?

if I use NumberOfSetBits(~n) it returns 30

Comment: The number of bytes each bit? you mean the number of bits each byte, and there is a constant for that `CHAR_BITS`

Comment: `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` is the storage size.  Most systems do not used padding.  To be pedantic, use `INT_MAX` and/or `INT_MIN` to determine true width - assuming code does not need to count 1 in any padding.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is found in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: `while (x != 0) { x = x >> 1; }` may be an infinite loop if `x < 0`

Comment: the code does not compile cleanly. 1) unused parameter: argc  2) unused parameter: argv  3) reached end of non void function (I.E. missing return statement

Comment: Would my solution be correct if I changed everything to unsigned int and fix what @user3629249 mentioned.

Comment: `NumberOfUnSetBits(0)` --> `0`

Comment: [`CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - __builtin_popcount(x)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Comment: `unsigned int NumberOfUnSetBits(unsigned int x) { NumberOfSetBits(~x); }` should work.

Comment: @chux Yep I know that one. I am wondering how would I do that without the ~ operator

Comment: `unsigned int NumberOfUnSetBits(unsigned int x) { NumberOfSetBits_Positive(UINT_MAX) - NumberOfSetBits(x); }`.  I used variations on this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a problem on some systems because you right shift a signed integer in your bit-counting function, which may shift 1's into the MSB each time for negative integers.
Use `unsigned int` (or just `unsigned`) instead:

```
int NumberOfSetBits(unsigned x)
{
    int count = 0;
    //printf("x is: %d\n", x);
    while (x != 0) {
        //printf("%d\n", x);
        count += (x & 1);
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you fix that part of the problem, you can solve the other with:

```
int nbits = NumberOfSetBits(~n);
```

where `~` bitwise inverts the value in `n`, and hence the 'set bit count' counts the bits that were zeros.

There are also faster algorithms for counting the number of bits set: see [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: Nice and simple use of ~

Comment: You have forgotten I guess the special case: when we input `0` it needs to return `1`

Answer (score 0):

here is a proper way to count the number of zeores in a binary number

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int binaryCount(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int nb=0; // will count the number of zeores 
    if(x==0) //for the case zero we need to return 1
        return 1;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        if ((x & 1) == 0) // the condition for getting the most right bit in the number
        {
            nb++;
        }
        x=x>>1; // move to the next bit 
    }
    return nb;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    printf("input the number x:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("the number of 0 in the binary number of %d is %u \n",x,binaryCount(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that if the compiler implements an arithmetic right shift for signed integers and you try to count the bits in a negative number, the loop will never finish.  The behaviour of your code depends on an implementation-defined behaviour.  You can avoid that by changing the type of the argument to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Very pleased to learn every time new things from you @JonathanLeffler ! :)

Comment: @Meninx Your code returns 0 for input 3. That doesn't seem right?

Comment: 3 in base 2 is 11 so there is no zero that's why it returns 0 ! @CodeCrack

Comment: @Meninx Shouldn't one be getting the size of unsigned int * 8(number of bits) and calculating all the 0s in it. I don't think it should be base 2?

Comment: the unsigned int is in 32 bit in the system so why do you want to multiply it by 8 ?

Comment: Warning: this implementation is wrong - look at the x=x>>1. If the last bit of the unsigned integer is not set, it will not count it, as x will be already 0 and the while loop stops before actually checking the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `NumberOfSetBits(int x)` version without assuming 2's complement nor absence of padding bits is a challenge.

[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810434/2410359) has the right approach: use `unsigned`.   - Just thought I'd try a generic `int` one.

The `x > 0`, OP's code work fine

```
int NumberOfSetBits_Positive(int x) {
  int count = 0;
  while (x != 0) {
    count += (x & 1);
    x = x >> 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Use the following to find the bit width and not count padding bits.

```
BitWidth = NumberOfSetBits_Positive(INT_MAX)  + 1;
```

With this, the count of 0 or 1 bits is trivial.

```
int NumberOfClearBits(int x) {
  return NumberOfSetBits_Positive(INT_MAX)  + 1 - NumberOfSetBits(x);
}

int NumberOfSetBits_Negative(int x) {
  return NumberOfSetBits_Positive(INT_MAX)  + 1 - NumberOfSetBits_Positive(~x);
}
```

All that is left is to find the number of bits set when x is 0.  +0 is easy, the answer is 0, but -0 (1's compliment or sign magnitude) is BitWidth or 1.

```
int NumberOfSetBits(int x) {
  if (x > 0) return NumberOfSetBits_Positive(x);
  if (x < 0) return NumberOfSetBits_Negative(x);

  // Code's assumption: Only 1 or 2 forms of 0.  
  /// There may be more because of padding.
  int zero = 0;
  // is x has same bit pattern as +0
  if (memcmp(&x, &zero, sizeof x) == 0) return 0;
  // Assume -0
  return NumberOfSetBits_Positive(INT_MAX)  + 1 - NumberOfSetBits_Positive(~x);
}
```